# How to run gdal_proximity in python rather than command line?

Tags: raster, gdal, shapefile, polygon, proximity

I have a folder of raster files, each containing a single rasterized polygon, where a value of 1 is burned into the polygon shapes, and where all else is no data (or could be simply changed to 0). I would like to loop through this folder to run Euclidean distance on each of the individual raster files. To do this I would like to use `gdal_proximity`, though I would like to use this as a python function rather than as a command line command. I am referring to this GDAL gdal_proximity documentation here: https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_proximity.html

Referencing this resource, the command line syntax looks like:

```
gdal_proximity.py <srcfile> <dstfile> [-srcband n] [-dstband n]
                  [-of format] [-co name=value]*
                  [-ot Byte/UInt16/UInt32/Float32/etc]
                  [-values n,n,n] [-distunits PIXEL/GEO]
                  [-maxdist n] [-nodata n] [-use_input_nodata YES/NO]
                  [-fixed-buf-val n]
```

How might I restructure this command syntax so that it works as a python function that I could simply run in Jupyter Notebook? I have referred to this "GDAL/OGR Python API" resource here: https://gdal.org/python/

Though I cannot find a python Jupyter Notebook-ready version of `gdal_proximity` here. How can I format this command to accept an example input raster of `raster.tif`? I am hoping I am using the terminology `API` correctly in this context, as meaning a python "version" of the original command. I see the gdal command is entered as `gdal_proximity.py`, but I am not sure if this would be the same thing as something like `gdal.Proximity()`.

Comment: The newest source code is here https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/swig/python/gdal-utils/osgeo_utils/gdal_proximity.py. It is plain Python.

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks. I also found this gdal proximity code that uses `gdal.ComputeProximity()` at https://github.com/marcelovilla/gdal-py-snippets/blob/master/scripts/compute_proximity.py. Seems a bit simpler.

Comment: gdal.ComputeProximity is what you want. Check examples in the test suite https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/alg/proximity.py